# How to prevent NetworkManager from taking control of a specific network interface?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I want to set up a mesh network using batman-adv, but NetworkManager keeps taking control of the second adapter... I need to be able to selectively tell NetworkManager not to manage one specific device.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkManager doesn't take control of interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so put the following line in that file:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

This will make NetworkManager ignore **wlan0**.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.10 and before, NetworkManager correctly ignored interfaces created by VirtualBox (vboxnet*). In 15.04 it insists on managing them and this solution does not work. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1485558 . In the meantime, any solution working on 15.04 would be nice!